# How do I select every pair of records in a table in Hive?

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

In Hive I have a table which contains two fields (lat and long). I would like to find top N shortest records for each record in the table. I think I can write a simple UDF (or leverage some existing UDF library) to compute the distance based on lat and long given a pair of lat and long.

Now to do this, I need to write a SQL to select every pair of records in the table. For example, if the table has 4 records (A, B, C and D), then I want to generate the following 6 pairs:

```
A, B
A, C
A, D
B, C
B, D
C, D
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hive supports `cross join`, so I would write this as:

```
select t1.col, t2.col
from t t1 cross join
     t t2
where t1.col < t2.col;
```

This formulation assumes that `col` is unique -- as in your example.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a cross apply.

```
 Select 
     t1.column as c1, 
     t2.column as c2
  From table as t1
Cross apply
   Table as t2
Where t1.column <> t2.column
```